# How to choose field value between two fields of different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with fields tbl_room(room_id,cat_id,room_price) and tbl_category(cat_id,cat_price).

Is there any way to check and if room_price is null then put the value of cat_price

select price(if room_price is null show cat_price else room_price)

Sth like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming the relation between tbl_room to tbl_category
is `1:1` relationship

```
select 
tr.room_id, tr.cat_id, 
coalesce(tr.room_price, tc.cat_price) as price
from tbl_room as tr
left join tbl_category tc
on tr.cat_id=tc.cat_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i have even tried IFNULL(tr.room_price, tc.cat_price) as price it works as well.. anyway thank u for the answer.

Comment: One more question... can we use that price in where clause? i mean 

select 
tr.room_id, tr.cat_id, 
coalesce(tr.room_price, tc.cat_price) as price
from tbl_room as tr
left join tbl_category tc
on tr.cat_id=tc.cat_id where (Not NULL)price>25;

Comment: can use HAVING `... HAVING price>25`